# Java: Elegantly returning an Object in an Optional<Object> if present?

Tags: java

Currently, I have the following code that works:

```
    //in class Bar
        
        public Foo getFooIfItIsPresent(String param) {
                Optional<Foo> result = loadOptionalFoo(param);
                if (result.isPresent()) {
                    return result.get();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
        
    // main driver code
    
    Foo foo = Bar.getFooIfItIsPresent(param);
                        
    if (foo != null) {
       // Currently just print, but might want to do stuff like pass foo to another object, etc.
       System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
    }
```

This is kind of ugly, because I am checking for null explicitly; in addition, I have a convoluted function `getFooIfItIsPresent` that exists for the sole purpose of the `isPresent()` dance. I would want to do something like:

```
    Bar.loadOptionalFoo(param).ifPresent((foo) -> {
    // Print, or whatever I wanna do!
    System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
    });
```

I know this doesn't compile. There's been a very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878076/returning-from-java-optional-ifpresent) question, and I've tried a bunch of stuff, but the compiler complains. Eg:

```
    Bar.loadOptionalFoo(week).map(foo -> {
    // Print, or whatever I wanna do!
                                System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
                            }).filter(Objects::nonNull);
```

Yes, the code above is nonsensical, but I can't seem to wrap my head around getting an elegant solution for this, so a bit of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Would the Null Object Pattern be an approach worth pursing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Comment: What is the compilation error here? You don't seem to have a parsing error, so I would assume that your lambda is incompatible with Consumer interface?

Comment: Yeah, basically. Here's a snippet of the error: `reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      missing return value)`

Comment: @BrentWorden Actually that might be suitable here. The reason my Foo is `Optional` is because it might just be empty (rather than absent) while loading it, which is what I understood from reading the wikipedia link? In that case, are you suggesting that the check for null is acceptable?

Comment: True: map() takes a Function<U,V> and your lambda does not return, but I don't see the point in your case: your are not trying to handle the "if not there" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

The code you showed saying “I know this doesn't compile” actually *should* compile. That code is your solution.

Using similar code, see this method:

```
public Optional < DayOfWeek > getFavoriteDayOfWeek ( )
{
    return Optional.ofNullable( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );  // Silly implementation for demonstration.
}
```

…called like this:

```
this.getFavoriteDayOfWeek().ifPresent(
        ( DayOfWeek dow ) -> { … dow.get() …  }
);
```

…run [live successfully at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/uyf2xs).

Keep in mind that an `Optional` is its own object, wrapping some other object as its payload. So be careful about your type declarations: `Optional<DayOfWeek> someVar` versus `DayOfWeek someVar`.

[image: table showing how a declaration of Optional creates a payload object wrapped in another object, an Optional object]

## Return the `Optional`

If a null is an acceptable value in your domain, then return the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html). Returning a `null` unwrapped from within an `Optional` defeats the purpose of an `Optional`.

The [purpose of an `Optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/642706) is to signal to the calling method that a null is indeed a valid possibility. The type system of Java is being used to remind the calling programmer to code for the possibility of a `null`. An `Optional` object is like a big [safety-orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_orange) traffic sign saying: “Beware: possible NULL ahead”.

Returning just `null` unwrapped from within an `Optional` adds no value, and makes for brittle code.

The code shown in the Question is jumping through extra hoops needlessly, just introducing an extra level of indirection with no benefit. The calling method should indeed receive an `Optional` if a payload of `null` is a valid result.

So this:

```
//in class Bar
    
    public Foo getFooIfItIsPresent(String param) {
            Optional<Foo> result = loadOptionalFoo(param);
            if (result.isPresent()) {
                return result.get();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    
// main driver code

Foo foo = Bar.getFooIfItIsPresent(param);
                    
if (foo != null) {
   // Currently just print, but might want to do stuff like pass foo to another object, etc.
   System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
}
```

…should be:

```
//in class Bar
    
// ➥ Delete this method `getFooIfItIsPresent`. Adds no value.
//     public Foo getFooIfItIsPresent(String param)
```

…and…

```
// main driver code

Optional<Foo> result = someBar.loadOptionalFoo( param );
                    
if ( result.isPresent() ) {
   // Currently just print, but might want to do stuff like pass foo to another object, etc.
   Foo foo = result.get() ;  // Calling `get` is safe because we checked for null in the `if … isPresent` line above.
   System.out.println( foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse() ) ;
}
```

Notice how we call `Optional::get` only after checking for null by calling `Optional::ifPresent`.

The [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class offers various methods if you want to address the `if else` condition where the `Optional` is empty with no `Foo` object present. See methods such as [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)), [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)), and [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()).

## Your problematic code should indeed compile

You said this code does not compile:

```
Bar.loadOptionalFoo(param).ifPresent((foo) -> {
// Print, or whatever I wanna do!
System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
});
```

Actually, that code should compile. It is perfectly reasonable to do, another variation of what I showed as a solution above.

Here is a similar example. I make the method `getFavoriteDayOfWeek` which returns an `Optional< DayOfWeek >` using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum class built into Java. If a favorite day is registered, the method returns an `Optional` holding a `DayOfWeek` object. If no favorite has yet been determined, the method returns an empty `Optional`. Here is our dummy version of that method.

```
public Optional < DayOfWeek > getFavoriteDayOfWeek ( )
{
    return Optional.ofNullable( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
}
```

Calling that method using code similar to your code:

```
this.getFavoriteDayOfWeek().ifPresent(
        ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek ) -> {
            // Print, or whatever I wanna do!
            System.out.println( dayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) );
        }
);
```

When run:

> mercredi

> INFO - Done running demo.

You can change the `WEDNESDAY` object with `null` to experiment.

```
public Optional < DayOfWeek > getFavoriteDayOfWeek ( )
{
    return Optional.ofNullable( null  );
}
```

When run, we see that the `System.out.println( dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(…` code is never called because the conditional test for our `Optional<DayOfWeek>` actually containing a `DayOfWeek` object ([`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent())) was not met. We see output only from our second `System.out.println`, for "Done running".

> INFO - Done running demo.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/uyf2xs).

## Making an `Optional`

The body of your Question seems to be asking about extracting a value from an `Optional`. I showed that above.

The title of your Question seems to be about wrapping a value in an `Optional`.

- If you know you want to return a `null`, return `Optional.empty()`.
- If returning something that may or may not be null, return `Optional.ofNullable( x )`.
- If returning something that should definitely *not* be null in that situation, return `Optional.of( x )`. That method throws `NullPointerException` if the value is null. Use this method when the presence of a null means something went very wrong with your app.

---

A tip, by the way, after seeing your use of `if (foo != null) {`:

If you do need to test for a `null`, I suggest instead of using `x != null` or `x == null` that you instead use the [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) class methods, [`Objects.nonNull​( Object obj )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) and [`Objects.isNull( Object obj )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)), respectively.

Even better, in a situation where the presence of a null in intolerable, meaning a major unexpected failure in your code, call [`Objects.requireNonNull​( T obj )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)). This method throws `NullPointerException` if receiving a null. Even better, this method returns the object passed. This makes it perfect for assigning passed arguments to other variables.

```
public void doSomething( final Fruit fruit , final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek ) 
{
    this.fruit = Objects.requireNonNull( fruit ) ;
    this.dayOfWeek = Objects.requireNonNull( dayOfWeek ) ;
}
```

Last tip: Java 14 brings more helpful `NullPointerException` objects, better pinpointing the place of failure. See [*JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358).

Comment: Actually yeah, the "problematic" code does compile when I inspect it. Looking back through version control, it seems I mixed up and the lambda parameter as another Optional again, which caused a compile error and threw me off. I feel silly now :( That, being said, I think your answer gives the best explanation of the purpose and practices for using `Optional` correctly, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

I fails to understand your problem with ifPresent since you are not even handling the case where the value is empty: why not use a method reference?

Have some method take a `Foo` parameter and do whatever:

```
class X {

  private Optional<Foo> loadFoo(String name) {...}
  private void consumeFoo(Foo foo) {...}

  void doSomething(String name) {
    this.loadFoo(name).ifPresent(this::consumeFoo);
  }
}
```

Also you can do

```
return result.orElse(null);
```

Instead of:

```
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return result.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You're right, the member reference is what evaded me and is a good solution to this, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Basil, but here's another possibility :

```
Bar.loadOptionalFoo(week)
    .map(foo -> 
            String.format("%s %s",
            foo.getSomething(),
            foo.getSomethingElse()))
   .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return `null` more elegantly, then have that null check :). Or if you don't want to have `null` check, than you can return `Optional` and do `isPresent` check

```
public Foo getFoo(String param) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(loadOptionalFoo(param)).orElse(null);
}

Foo foo = Bar.getFoo(param);
                    
if (foo != null) {
   // Currently just print, but might want to do stuff like pass foo to another object, etc.
   System.out.println(foo.getSomething() + foo.getSomethingElse());
}
```